# Mostrar Propiedad de una entidad de segundo nivel en datagridview c#

Tags: c#

Buenas tardes, Estoy llenando un datagriview con una lista cuya entidad es:

```
public class ECliente
{
    public int CLI_CODIGO { get; set; }
    public string CLI_NOMBRE { get; set; }
    public string CLI_RUC { get; set; }
    public string CLI_DIRECCION { get; set; }
    ...
    ...
    public int EJE_CODIGO_AM { get; set; }
    public int TP_CODIGO { get; set; }

    public ECiudad CIUDAD { get; set; }
```

}

y la entidad ECiudad es la siguiente

```
public class ECiudad
{
    public int CIU_CODIGO { get; set; }
    public string CIU_NOMBRE { get; set; }
    public string CIU_ESTADO { get; set; }
    public string CIU_RUBRO_CON { get; set; }
}
```

y en la capa negocio tengo el llenado de mi lista.

```
    public List<ECliente> GetListClientes(string Criterio)
    {
        List<ECliente> lista = new List<ECliente>();
        ....
        ....
```

}

En el formulario tengo un boton toolStrip cuyo evento es:

```
    private void tsBuscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         ...
        dgvLista.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        dgvLista.DataSource = nCliente.GetListClientes(sb.ToString());
    }
```

y me llena el datagridview

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Deseo que se muestre el valor de la propiedad CIU_NOMBRE de la entidad eCIUDAD??

Ademas puedo usar EF6 con SQL Server 2000 Express Edition ????, Ya que todas las entidades lo estoy creando manualmente...

Gracias por su amable ayuda y sugerencias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sobrescribe la función .ToString() en la clase secundaria devolviendo la propiedad que quieras y ya lo tendrás solucionado.

Sería algo así:

```
public class ECiudad
{
    public int CIU_CODIGO { get; set; }
    public string CIU_NOMBRE { get; set; }
    public string CIU_ESTADO { get; set; }
    public string CIU_RUBRO_CON { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return CIU_NOMBRE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfecto Gracias